# PyTorch For Loop Optimisations and Speedup techniques

Tags: python, for-loop, pytorch

This is a problem I've now encountered three times in the past year.

I appreciate that in certain scenarios, a vectorized solution will be better and considerably faster.

However IMHO, there is a trade off between discovering a vectorizing solution and using what is essentially a for loop (or double for loop). Discovering the vectorized solution (if there exists indeed one) may take a lot more effort, trial and error, research and so on.

The code that is the simplest form (the double for loop in this case) almost always ends up being a bottle neck for me, but takes very little time to implement and test.

Here's an example:

```py
@torch.jit.script    
def seq_prob(t_samples: torch.Tensor):
    i = 0
    probs = [0] * len(t_samples)    
    for t_i in torch.unbind(t_samples):
        for t_k in torch.unbind(t_samples):
            is_same = torch.all(torch.isclose(t_i, t_k, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=False))
            if is_same is True:
                probs[i] += 1
        i += 1
    return probs
```

The `torch.unbind` simply treats the outer dimension as the iterable. In some cases, I have spent a considerable amount of time to derive a vectorized form of the loop, which usually results in masking, cumsum, index select and a variety of built-in pytorch methods, complicating the logic compared to a for-loop but making it faster.

Similarly, using CUDA and `@torch.jit` sometimes helps (but not always).

Therefore my questions are:

- When using some form of for loop in pytorch (e.g., `torch.unbind` or `torch.chunk` or anything similar) whose aim is to iterate over a dimension and perform an operation
- Is there a way, a golden standard, some option, which can speed things up (vectorizing excluded)?
- If vectorizing is the only option, then what would be a good first plan of attack? Take as an example the code shown above which computes observations of a value within a sample set given some tolerance.

Comment: There is an error in your code, torch booleans dont work this way: `if same is True` must be changed to `if same`. You can play around with this line of code to understand the torchy behaviour: `1 if torch.ones(1, dtype=torch.bool)[0] else 0` versus `1 if torch.ones(1, dtype=torch.bool)[0] is True else 0`

Answer (score 1):

I could not come up with a vectorized version straigt away, but I fixed a bug and reduced the loop runs by more than 50%. Also, `torch.unbind` is not needed here, you can iterate an array (or tensor) over the outer dimension out of the box.

I cannot provide you with a gold standard except for: vectorize when possible, don't do pairwise comparisons in both directions, when they can be avoided.

```
import torch

t = torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]])
torch.all(torch.isclose(t[0], t[0]))


t_samples = t
i = 0
probs = torch.zeros(len(t_samples))
for id_i, t_i in enumerate(t_samples):
    # dont do the same calculation twice, start at id_i + 1
    for id_j, t_k in enumerate(t_samples[id_i+1:], start=id_i+1):
        is_same = torch.all(
            torch.isclose(t_i, t_k, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=False)
        )
        if is_same:  # you had an error here, torch booleans dont work your way
            probs[id_i] += 1  # compare A to B
            probs[id_j] += 1  # compare B to A
```

Comment: Thanks for the bug fix. Generally `torch.unbind` is faster than slicing and looping over a tensor (according to pytorch forums).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the optimized version in my other answer, this is a vectorized version for your problem:

```
import torch

# sample data with a duplicate at index 0 and 1
t = torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]])

# indices of all unique pairwise comparisons (triu=upper triangle). Offset 1 since we don't need to compare A to A
indices1, indices2 = torch.triu_indices(row=len(t), col=len(t), offset=1)

# check for each unique pair (e.g. treat A<->B same as B<->A) if values are the same (e.g. difference is zero)
matches = torch.isclose(
    (t[indices1] - t[indices2]).abs().sum(axis=1),
    torch.zeros(len(t)),
    rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08
)

# get the indices for cases where differences were zero (matches!)
matched_indices = torch.cat([indices1[:, None], indices2[:, None]], 1)[matches]

# container for probs
probs = torch.zeros(len(t))

# increase the probs for those indices that have duplicates
probs[matched_indices] += 1
```

Note: Consider that the matrix will roughly contain (n**2) / 2 elements and might explode for huge n.

Comment: That's nice, and yes I would argue this is much better. I've ended up using `torch.roll` and producing the same indices as `torch.triu_indices` but I suspect that `triu_indices` is considerably faster, since it results in one call to the underlying cuda code, whereas `roll` has to use multiple calls. And yeah, memory is an issue, in some cases I've had to run extremely large cosine similarities on very large embeddings, ending up with OOM all the time. But this works very nicely, I'll keep this in mind for future reference.